# Como otimizar consulta Hibernate

Tags: java, otimização, hql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em JAVA e utilizo o Hibernante para gerar minhas consultas com o banco.
Preciso resolver o seguinte problema:

Tenho algumas classes que pertencem a uma entidade e preciso executar um método que me retorne alguns campos das classe (não todos) mas o Hibernante faz um Hql que pega todos os campos e isso acaba demorando muito mais do que deveria.
Tem como fazer algum tipo de filtro para pegar apenas os campos que preciso?

Aqui um exemplo genérico do que  está  acontecendo.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entidade1")
public class Entidade1 extends GenericEntidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    private Integer campo1;
    private Integer campo2;
    private Integer campo3;
    private Integer campo4;
    private Integer campo5;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo1
     */
    public Integer getCampo1() {
        return campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo1 the campo1 to set
     */
    public void setCampo1(Integer campo1) {
        this.campo1 = campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo2
     */
    public Integer getCampo2() {
        return campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo2 the campo2 to set
     */
    public void setCampo2(Integer campo2) {
        this.campo2 = campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo3
     */
    public Integer getCampo3() {
        return campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo3 the campo3 to set
     */
    public void setCampo3(Integer campo3) {
        this.campo3 = campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo4
     */
    public Integer getCampo4() {
        return campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo4 the campo4 to set
     */
    public void setCampo4(Integer campo4) {
        this.campo4 = campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo5
     */
    public Integer getCampo5() {
        return campo5;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo5 the campo5 to set
     */
    public void setCampo5(Integer campo5) {
        this.campo5 = campo5;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entidade2")
public class Entidade2 extends GenericEntidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @return the serialVersionUID
     */
    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    private Integer campo1;
    private Integer campo2;
    private Integer campo3;
    private Integer campo4;
    private Integer campo5;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo1
     */
    public Integer getCampo1() {
        return campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo1 the campo1 to set
     */
    public void setCampo1(Integer campo1) {
        this.campo1 = campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo2
     */
    public Integer getCampo2() {
        return campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo2 the campo2 to set
     */
    public void setCampo2(Integer campo2) {
        this.campo2 = campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo3
     */
    public Integer getCampo3() {
        return campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo3 the campo3 to set
     */
    public void setCampo3(Integer campo3) {
        this.campo3 = campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo4
     */
    public Integer getCampo4() {
        return campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo4 the campo4 to set
     */
    public void setCampo4(Integer campo4) {
        this.campo4 = campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo5
     */
    public Integer getCampo5() {
        return campo5;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo5 the campo5 to set
     */
    public void setCampo5(Integer campo5) {
        this.campo5 = campo5;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entidade3")
public class Entidade3 extends GenericEntidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @return the serialVersionUID
     */
    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    private Integer campo1;
    private Integer campo2;
    private Integer campo3;
    private Integer campo4;
    private Integer campo5;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo1
     */
    public Integer getCampo1() {
        return campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo1 the campo1 to set
     */
    public void setCampo1(Integer campo1) {
        this.campo1 = campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo2
     */
    public Integer getCampo2() {
        return campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo2 the campo2 to set
     */
    public void setCampo2(Integer campo2) {
        this.campo2 = campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo3
     */
    public Integer getCampo3() {
        return campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo3 the campo3 to set
     */
    public void setCampo3(Integer campo3) {
        this.campo3 = campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo4
     */
    public Integer getCampo4() {
        return campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo4 the campo4 to set
     */
    public void setCampo4(Integer campo4) {
        this.campo4 = campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo5
     */
    public Integer getCampo5() {
        return campo5;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo5 the campo5 to set
     */
    public void setCampo5(Integer campo5) {
        this.campo5 = campo5;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entidade4")

public class Entidade4 extends GenericEntidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @return the serialVersionUID
     */
    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Entidade5 campo1;
    private Integer campo2;
    private Integer campo3;
    private Integer campo4;
    private Integer campo5;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo1
     */
    public Entidade5 getCampo1() {
        return campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo1 the campo1 to set
     */
    public void setCampo1(Entidade5 campo1) {
        this.campo1 = campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo2
     */
    public Integer getCampo2() {
        return campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo2 the campo2 to set
     */
    public void setCampo2(Integer campo2) {
        this.campo2 = campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo3
     */
    public Integer getCampo3() {
        return campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo3 the campo3 to set
     */
    public void setCampo3(Integer campo3) {
        this.campo3 = campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo4
     */
    public Integer getCampo4() {
        return campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo4 the campo4 to set
     */
    public void setCampo4(Integer campo4) {
        this.campo4 = campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo5
     */
    public Integer getCampo5() {
        return campo5;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo5 the campo5 to set
     */
    public void setCampo5(Integer campo5) {
        this.campo5 = campo5;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entidade5")

public class Entidade5 extends GenericEntidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @return the serialVersionUID
     */
    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    private Integer campo1;
    private Integer campo2;
    private Integer campo3;
    private Integer campo4;
    private Integer campo5;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo1
     */
    public Integer getCampo1() {
        return campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo1 the campo1 to set
     */
    public void setCampo1(Integer campo1) {
        this.campo1 = campo1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo2
     */
    public Integer getCampo2() {
        return campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo2 the campo2 to set
     */
    public void setCampo2(Integer campo2) {
        this.campo2 = campo2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo3
     */
    public Integer getCampo3() {
        return campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo3 the campo3 to set
     */
    public void setCampo3(Integer campo3) {
        this.campo3 = campo3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo4
     */
    public Integer getCampo4() {
        return campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo4 the campo4 to set
     */
    public void setCampo4(Integer campo4) {
        this.campo4 = campo4;
    }

    /**
     * @return the campo5
     */
    public Integer getCampo5() {
        return campo5;
    }

    /**
     * @param campo5 the campo5 to set
     */
    public void setCampo5(Integer campo5) {
        this.campo5 = campo5;
    }

}

@Entity

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "EntidadePrincipal.getAll", query
            = "SELECT  c from EntidadePrincipal c")
})
public class EntidadePrincipal implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Entidade1 obra;
    @ManyToOne
    private Entidade2 fornecedor;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Entidade3> notas;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Entidade4> itens;

    public List doAll() {
        return new GenericDaoImpl().getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("EntidadePrincipal.getAll").getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the obra
     */
    public Entidade1 getObra() {
        return obra;
    }

    /**
     * @param obra the obra to set
     */
    public void setObra(Entidade1 obra) {
        this.obra = obra;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fornecedor
     */
    public Entidade2 getFornecedor() {
        return fornecedor;
    }

    /**
     * @param fornecedor the fornecedor to set
     */
    public void setFornecedor(Entidade2 fornecedor) {
        this.fornecedor = fornecedor;
    }

    /**
     * @return the notas
     */
    public List<Entidade3> getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    /**
     * @param notas the notas to set
     */
    public void setNotas(List<Entidade3> notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    /**
     * @return the itens
     */
    public List<Entidade4> getItens() {
        return itens;
    }

    /**
     * @param itens the itens to set
     */
    public void setItens(List<Entidade4> itens) {
        this.itens = itens;
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<kuab.oc.model.entity.EntidadePrincipal> lista = new kuab.oc.model.entity.EntidadePrincipal().doAll();

        System.out.print(lista.get(0).getFornecedor());
        System.out.print(lista.get(0).getItens().get(0).getCampo1().getId());
        System.out.print(lista.get(0).getNotas().get(0).getCampo1());
        System.out.print(lista.get(0).getObra().getId());

    }

}
```

Aqui está o sql que o Hibernate gera e como vocês podem perceber ele retorna todos os campos.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        entidadepr0_.id as id1_6_,
        entidadepr0_.fornecedor_id as forneced2_6_,
        entidadepr0_.obra_id as obra_id3_6_ 
    from
        EntidadePrincipal entidadepr0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        entidade2x0_.id as id1_59_0_,
        entidade2x0_.campo1 as campo2_59_0_,
        entidade2x0_.campo2 as campo3_59_0_,
        entidade2x0_.campo3 as campo4_59_0_,
        entidade2x0_.campo4 as campo5_59_0_,
        entidade2x0_.campo5 as campo6_59_0_ 
    from
        entidade2 entidade2x0_ 
    where
        entidade2x0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        entidade1x0_.id as id1_58_0_,
        entidade1x0_.campo1 as campo2_58_0_,
        entidade1x0_.campo2 as campo3_58_0_,
        entidade1x0_.campo3 as campo4_58_0_,
        entidade1x0_.campo4 as campo5_58_0_,
        entidade1x0_.campo5 as campo6_58_0_ 
    from
        entidade1 entidade1x0_ 
    where
        entidade1x0_.id=?
kuab.oc.model.entity.teste.Entidade2@1a91c9bHibernate: 
    select
        itens0_.EntidadePrincipal_id as Entidade1_6_0_,
        itens0_.itens_id as itens_id2_8_0_,
        entidade4x1_.id as id1_61_1_,
        entidade4x1_.campo1_id as campo6_61_1_,
        entidade4x1_.campo2 as campo2_61_1_,
        entidade4x1_.campo3 as campo3_61_1_,
        entidade4x1_.campo4 as campo4_61_1_,
        entidade4x1_.campo5 as campo5_61_1_,
        entidade5x2_.id as id1_62_2_,
        entidade5x2_.campo1 as campo2_62_2_,
        entidade5x2_.campo2 as campo3_62_2_,
        entidade5x2_.campo3 as campo4_62_2_,
        entidade5x2_.campo4 as campo5_62_2_,
        entidade5x2_.campo5 as campo6_62_2_ 
    from
        EntidadePrincipal_entidade4 itens0_ 
    inner join
        entidade4 entidade4x1_ 
            on itens0_.itens_id=entidade4x1_.id 
    left outer join
        entidade5 entidade5x2_ 
            on entidade4x1_.campo1_id=entidade5x2_.id 
    where
        itens0_.EntidadePrincipal_id=?
1Hibernate: 
    select
        notas0_.EntidadePrincipal_id as Entidade1_6_0_,
        notas0_.notas_id as notas_id2_7_0_,
        entidade3x1_.id as id1_60_1_,
        entidade3x1_.campo1 as campo2_60_1_,
        entidade3x1_.campo2 as campo3_60_1_,
        entidade3x1_.campo3 as campo4_60_1_,
        entidade3x1_.campo4 as campo5_60_1_,
        entidade3x1_.campo5 as campo6_60_1_ 
    from
        EntidadePrincipal_entidade3 notas0_ 
    inner join
        entidade3 entidade3x1_ 
            on notas0_.notas_id=entidade3x1_.id 
    where
        notas0_.EntidadePrincipal_id=?
```

Simplificando, eu quero fazer a consulta de uma forma que me  retorne apenas os atributos que utilizei na classe Main, e no HQL não tenha todos estes atributos descritos. Tem alguma forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 2):

Tem sim.

Existem [várias maneiras](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). A mais popular é criar uma classe específica para receber apenas os atributos que quer. Esta classe é instanciada dentro do próprio HQL e você passa para o construtor da classe os atributos que quer passar.

Imaginamos que para isto você criou um classe `br.com.projeto.dto.EntidadeDto` para receber apenas o `id`, `campo1` e `campo2`:

```
class EntidadeDto {

    private int id;
    private String campo1;
    private String campo2;

    EntidadeDto (int id, String campo1, String campo2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.campo1 = campo1;
        this.campo2 = campo2;
    }
    //getters
}
```

Seu HQL poderia ser:

```
SELECT new br.com.projeto.dto.EntidadeDto(e.id, e.campo1, e.campo2) 
FROM Entidade1 e WHERE e.id = 1
```

Assim, você receberia do `getResultList()` um `List<EntidadeDto>`.

Comment: Eu dei um upvote, mas considere pelo menos citar quais são essas várias maneiras para termos uma referência na própria resposta.